# INSERT INTO Table via ASP.NET MVC doesn't work correctly

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm creating an ASP.NET MVC project with SQL Server connection. SELECT query is working fine, but i want to use INSERT INTO which is a problem here. All is going well, application loading page but record is not adding in database table.

Here is my Controller:

```
public ActionResult L4Change(L4 model)
{
    var UserManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    var user = UserManager.FindByEmail(model.UserID);
    var userid = user.Id;
    var userfname = user.FirstName;
    var userlname = user.LastName;

    var doctor = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
    var doctorfname = doctor.FirstName;
    var doctorlname = doctor.LastName;

    string startdate = model.StartDate;
    string finishdate = model.FinishDate;
    string reason = model.Reason;
        
    string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;

    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon))
        {
            /*String query = @"INSERT INTO [aspnet-E-Pacjent-20200804074349].[dbo].[L4] "
                                + "VALUES ('"+ userid + "', '" + userfname +"', '" + userlname +"', '" + startdate +"', '"+ finishdate +"', '"+ reason + "', '" + doctorfname +  "', '" + doctorlname + "');";*/

            String query = "INSERT INTO [aspnet-E-Pacjent-20200804074349].[dbo].[L4] VALUES(@UserID, @UserFName, @UserLName, @StartDate, @FinishDate, @Reason, @DoctorFName, @DoctorLName);";

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, con);

            command.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.NChar, 255, userid);
            command.Parameters.Add("@UserFName", SqlDbType.NChar, 50, userfname);
            command.Parameters.Add("@UserLName", SqlDbType.NChar, 50, userlname);
            command.Parameters.Add("@StartDate", SqlDbType.Date, 50, startdate);
            command.Parameters.Add("@FinishDate", SqlDbType.Date, 50, finishdate);
            command.Parameters.Add("@Reason", SqlDbType.NChar, 50, reason);
            command.Parameters.Add("@DoctorFName", SqlDbType.NChar, 50, doctorfname);
            command.Parameters.Add("@DoctorLName", SqlDbType.NChar, 50, doctorlname);

            da.InsertCommand = command;

            return RedirectToAction("DoctorControl","Home");
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return View("Error");
    }         
}
```

I tried 2 solutions First query is commented and 2nd is running.

Comment: Looks like there's no `Update` method.

Comment: @manabu So After Insert should i Updated added records? When I'm using INSERT INTO in SqlExpress is working corectly.

Comment: You don't need to use DataAdapter. You should do `command.ExecuteNonQuery` to execute the command against the database and it will insert the row in the table.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya You are right, thanks!

Comment: This usage is quite old. I don't remember exactly but I think you should be able to use `da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()` directly  too, if you want to work disconnected mode